# renewcommand cite with one or two arguments

Tags: lyx, environments

I need to renewcommand `\cite`. I used the following:

```
\let\citeOld\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{{\mbox{\citeOld{#1}}}}
```

and works correctly for citations like `\cite{Taylor}`. The problem is that if I have citations like `\cite[eq. (1)]{Taylor}` I receive an error. If I use:

```
\let\citeOld\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{\mbox{\citeOld[#1]{#2}}}
```

I don't have errors but something like `[13, ]` on output when using `\cite{Taylor}`, with an unwanted `,`.

Is it possible to renewcommand cite such as it works for both cases?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `\cite` has a peculiar definition; it is a "robusted" command, but this is the minor aspect. It's definition, after the first two steps in which no argument is examined, is

```
\@ifnextchar[{\@tempswatrue\@citex}{\@tempswafalse\@citex[]}
```

and this is the main problem; you can't do simply `\let\citeOld\cite`, but need to modify the behavior of `\@citex`, which is the macro responsible for absorbing the arguments.

### Simple way

```
\makeatletter
\let\@citexOld\@citex
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\mbox{\@citexOld[#1]{#2}}}
\makeatother
```

### With `xparse`

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro,xparse}
\LetLtxMacro\citeOld\cite
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cite}{om}
 {\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\mbox{\citeOld{#2}}}{\mbox{\citeOld[#1]{#2}}}
```

### With `regexpatch`

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd{\@citex}
  { \A \c{leavevmode} (.*) }
  { \c{mbox} \cB\{ \1 \cE\} }
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

This changes the initial `\leavevmode` in the replacement text of `\@citex` with `\mbox{` and adds the matching `}` at the end.

Note that all of these will go wrong if you load the package `natbib` and possibly other packages meant to modify citation commands.

Comment: @Paolo Sorry, but I don't speak LyXish.

Comment: The Simple way works fine, but not in my case. My more general problem is that I use LyX with Change tracking mode activated. In this case, LyX Underlines conflicts with \cite. In the preamble I used `\usepackage[pdftex]{changebar}

\makeatletter
\let\@citexOld\@citex
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\mbox{\@citexOld[#1]{#2}}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\lyxadded}[3]{{\protect\cbstart\color{lyxadded}
{}\uline{#3}\protect\cbend}}
\renewcommand{\lyxdeleted}[3]
{{\protect\cbstart\color{lyxdeleted}\protect\cbend}}` and I still have an error

Comment: Ok. However Lyx is just an editor for LaTeX.

Comment: @Paolo No, it isn't simply an editor. It wants you to do its way, rather than your own.

Comment: you're right, but I'm pretty sure that my problem is not LaTeX or LyX dependent.

Comment: @Paolo: In that case, please create a small document (in LyX) that recreates your problem and post the (full) LaTeX code as part of your question via [an edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/133148/edit).