# How to colour citation brackets?

Tags: biblatex, color, citing, biber, biblatex-ext

I am writing my thesis,
and my university provides a neat template that I am currently using.
Among the customised options the template has,
there is also a specific color that is used for titles, caption and so on.
At some point during the drafting I thought it would be nice
to be able to also see the citations in said color instead of a dull black,
so I started messing around with the `hyperref` package:

```
\definecolor{bluepoli}{cmyk}{0.4,0.1,0,0.4} % University colour definition for context
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, anchorcolor=black, citecolor=bluepoli,%
            filecolor=black, menucolor=black, runcolor=black, urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
```

The result though did not satisfy me, it actually looked worse,
because with this only the numbers inside the square brackets are coloured
(I am using `biber` with a `numeric-comp` style).
[image: Image with only link coloured]
I took a look at the `biblatex` package then to see
whether it offered any colouring options, but I remained dissatisfied.
I could just drop this whim,
but I couldn't wrap my head around the fact even books and papers
that use coloured links have the same, to my eyes, problem.
I thought about changing the text colour before and after invoking `\cite{}`
using `\renewcommand{}{}`,
but I am not very experienced with the mechanisms underneath LaTeX.
After a quick search I found this answer:
[renewcommand cite with one or two arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133148/renewcommand-cite-with-one-or-two-arguments),
and now my code looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\blup}[1]{\textcolor{bluepoli}{#1}} % Quick colour-setting command

\makeatletter
\let\@citexOld\@citex
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\blup{\@citexOld[#1]{#2}}}
\makeatother

\let\citeOld\cite % renew cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{{\blup{\citeOld{#1}}}}
\let\citetOld\citet % renew cite
\renewcommand{\citet}[1]{{\blup{\citetOld{#1}}}}
```

Which works, but it feels clumsy to do so for every citing command I might need.
I also did not realise that
what I defined changes also the colour of explicit authors citations.
[image: Image with both brackets and links coloured]
Is there a less clunky way to have only square brackets
and citations coloured? Is this actually heresy from a typographic standpoint?

---

Notes: yes I am aware that `\citet{}` is a command from `natbib`,
which only uses `bibtex`.
Originally the template used this package, but after increasing frustrations
I switched to `biber`

---

Edit(1): I provide here a minimal reproducible example
of the source code.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book} 

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=bluepoli]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{knuth74,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title = {Computer Programming As an Art},
    journal = {Commun. ACM},
    year = {1974},
    pages = {667--673},
}
@book{peterson93,
  author    = {Peter Peterson},
  title     = {The title of the work},
  publisher = {The name of the publisher},
  year      = {1993},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\definecolor{bluepoli}{cmyk}{0.4,0.1,0,0.4} % Define colour of citations and
\newcommand{\blup}[1]{\textcolor{bluepoli}{#1}} % its shortcut

\makeatletter % Redefine the macro of citex
\let\@citexOld\@citex
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\blup{\@citexOld[#1]{#2}}}
\makeatother
\let\citeOld\cite % Renew cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{{\blup{\citeOld{#1}}}}
\let\citetOld\citet % Renew citet
\renewcommand{\citet}[1]{{\blup{\citetOld{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}
This is a test~\cite{knuth74}.\\
\citet{peterson93} also reports a test.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

Edit(2): Thanks to @Accácio
for giving insight into the documentation
to refer to for the solution.
I decided to tidy up a bit this question.
The package extension `biblatex-ext` has a function
that is specifically designed to change the style
of the delimiters (in this case, their color).
It is necessary to change the style of citation in the
options of the `biblatex` first:

```
\usepackage[style=ext-numeric-comp,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
% the style is changed to 'ext-numeric-comp'
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{cite} % for the cite command
    {\textcolor{bluepoli}{\bibopenbracket}}  % left bracket
    {\textcolor{bluepoli}{\bibclosebracket}} % right bracket
```

At the moment I did not find a way
to change the brackets of ALL cite commands,
partly because the result I seek concerns in some cases
the outer delimiter, in others the inner delimiter,
like the author citation

```
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite} % for the textcite command
    {\textcolor{bluepoli}{\bibopenbracket}} % left INNER bracket
    {\textcolor{bluepoli}{\bibclosebracket}} % right INNER bracket
```

Which in the previous code produces the correct result.
[image: Inner delimiters are modified]
Instead, the modification of the external delimiters concerns
the wrapping of the entire citation, author included.
[image: Outer delimiters are modified]

Comment: As always on the cite, you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: @daleif thanks for the tip! I updated the question now.

Comment: Do remember that with very few exceptions `hyperref ` should be loaded last as it has to adapt to other packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a solution similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/69727169/9781176 by using [biblatex-ext](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) and the `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims` function:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=bluepoli]{hyperref}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=ext-numeric-comp,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{cite}{\textcolor{green}{\bibopenbracket}}{\textcolor{red}{\bibclosebracket}}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{knuth74,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title = {Computer Programming As an Art},
    journal = {Commun. ACM},
    year = {1974},
    pages = {667--673},
}
@book{peterson93,
  author    = {Peter Peterson},
  title     = {The title of the work},
  publisher = {The name of the publisher},
  year      = {1993},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\definecolor{bluepoli}{cmyk}{0.4,0.1,0,0.4} % Define colour of citations and
\newcommand{\blup}[1]{\textcolor{bluepoli}{#1}} % its shortcut
\makeatletter % Redefine the macro of citex

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}
This is a test~\cite{knuth74}.\\
\citep{peterson93} also reports a test.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image: result]

N.B: The citation style is changed to ext-numeric-comp

Comment: the biblatex itself has options for hyperref you should take a look at it https://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf

Comment: the use of biblatex-ext extension actually helped a lot! With just two lines I can put the color of the parentheses. Too bad it doesn't work with \citet, but I guess it is finally time to substitute all these command calls with the biblatex ones, and finally rule out natbib from my thesis

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wrapper argument of `\DeclareCiteCommand` to slip in another colouring command. We copy the definition of the relevant cite commands from from the style (in this case [`numeric-comp.cbx`, ll. 209-300](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/64156e27b9501bab86cab5ed9ee58e8a6a5ce67f/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric-comp.cbx#L209-L300)) and add `\textcolor{bluepoli}` (possibly via a helper command) to the wrapper argument.

Note that this will only add more colour to the citation. It will not change the link area of the citation.

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
  sorting=none,
  natbib=true,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=bluepoli]{hyperref}

\definecolor{bluepoli}{cmyk}{0.4,0.1,0,0.4}

\newcommand*{\mkbibcolbrackets}[1]{%
  \textcolor{bluepoli}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibcolbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibcolbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@textcite}[\textcolor{bluepoli}]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \textcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1] ipsum Sigfridsson e Ryde [1] with "[1]" and "Sigfridsson e Ryde [1]" in blue.]

Comment: Thanks @moewe. This looks very complicated!
I also looked at the git you linked, but I couldn't find out how to remove the color from the author part of the citation